# Silverlight fluidLayout fail

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, fluid-layout

So this is going to be a bit difficult to explain, but I'll give it a go an hopefully someone will recognize what I'm talking about.

So I have a `StackPanel` in which there are 3 `Buttons` and 3 `Lists` there are also 3 `VisualStates` that represent the "open" state of each list (it's an accordion).  By default each element's height is set to 0, and within it's respective state it's height is set to auto.  Fluid layout is turned on, so I can go from 0 -> auto...

tl;dr = I made an accordion with FluidLayout.

Inside one of my accordion panes, there is an `ItemsControl` I created a generated items template and in that there is an 'expander' control where you click a button and more content is shown.  This is also done with `VisualStates` and a FluidLayout is turned on. However when I try to expand my expanding control, it doesn't go smoothly from 0 height -> auto height as it should, it instead just appears.

Anyone run into similar problems?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I ended up reflecting the code, and this is done explicitly.

I guess it's another one of Microsoft's undocumented "features".

I wish I could get away with writing crap software and calling everything that doesn't work a "feature".